# Что не так с запросом mysql?

Tags: mysql

```
select a.*
from article as a
where a.status_id = 2 and count(select h.id from article_history as h where h.article_id = a.id and h.event_id = 5) = 0
```

[Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'select h.id from article_history as h where h.article_id = a.id and h.event_id =' at line 3

Comment: Скорее всего ругается на имя поля id. Попробуйте их обернуть так: h.`id`

Comment: @УстьянцевБорис сто лет уже так работаю. Никогда не ругалось. Не причем тут названия...

Comment: Хм. Разметка режет бектики. Это обратные апострофы (на клавише с ё).

Comment: @УстьянцевБорис да знаю я. Еще раз говорю - с названиями все в порядке. Их не надо экранировать. Ну даже заэкранировал - все равно не помогло.

Comment: А если заменить `count(select h.id from article_history as h where h.article_id = a.id and h.event_id = 5)` на `(select count(h.id) from article_history as h where h.article_id = a.id and h.event_id = 5)`? Хотя поидее смысл тот же

Comment: @Chubatiy ха! А так заработало! Спасибо!!! Хз в чем проблема была с этим запросом, вроде смысл действительно один и тот же...

Comment: @DarkByte насколько я знаю, `COUNT` нельзя использовать в `WHERE`: только в `SELECT` и в `HAVING`.

Comment: @Regent не знал

Comment: @Regent анналогичные сведения

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Замените

```
count(select h.id from article_history as h where h.article_id = a.id and h.event_id = 5)
```

на

```
(select count(h.id) from article_history as h where h.article_id = a.id and h.event_id = 5)
```

Как было озвученно в комментариях к вопросу участником **Regent**:

> COUNT нельзя использовать в WHERE: только в SELECT и в HAVING